# Escaping quotes in VB.NET (aspx.vb)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi all i have the following code

```
<%= Replace(FindAndReplace(objDR.Item("LENTAB_NAME") ),"'","\'") %>
```

in this we are replacing the ' character with \', which is working fine.
but when i tried to enter values like '"" then it is giving scripting error as

> ')' expected

i tried to replace this thing as  `Replace(string,"'"","\'"")`
but failed
can you please give me the solution to this!

Actually this is the code snippet

```
FoldersArray[FoldersArray.length] = new FoldersListItmes("<%= objDR.Item("TAB_ID") %>","<%= Replace(FindAndReplace(objDR.Item("LENTAB_NAME") ),"'","\\'") %>","<%= Replace(FindAndReplace(objDR.Item("TAB_NAME") ),"'","\'") %>" ,"<%=intCnt %>" )
```

i am using server side tags inside javascript function...

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like JavaScript to me, something more like JSP/ASP?

Comment: Is this classic ASP, ASP.Net, or what? (As @maerics says, although JavaScript relates to the problem, primarily the question is about the VB-esque language and framework you're using server-side.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine that you have to escape your escape character as well, since `\` has a special meaning when used inside strings.

So essentially use `"\\'"`.

Comment: To add to that, the inner double quote `"` should be escaped as well to `\"`, just like the single quote `\'`.

Comment: @Shef: Ah. :-) Sorry, I was looking at the first code snippet.

Comment: @Steve... i kept "\\'" in my code, still it is giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

You *could* just escape the quotes (you need to escape your backslash, as [@Steve Wang mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578691/how-to-escape-characters/6578724#6578724)), but then other characters (line newlines) will mess you up.

If you're using a recent version of ASP.Net, you may want to use the [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) to encode all of the necessary characters. Sadly, that appears to be quite new, in .Net 4.

*(That MSDN page mentions URL encoding, but I'm fairly sure that's just because Microsoft assigns their most entry-level staff to MSDN documentation; the function has nothing to do with URL encoding.)*